# SQL call with multiple IF statements in HAVING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL call where we need to return all records where this month's purchases for a customer is 5% higher than last month or 5 packages higher, whichever is greater. I need to have this all run in a single SQL call, and after a lot of trial and error, I'm at a total loss. This is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
   CASE WHEN date_part('month', reported_date) = date_part('month', current_date) 
   AND date_part('year', reported_date) = date_part('year', current_date) then total_orders 
   ELSE 0 END) thismonthpurchases, 
  SUM(
   CASE WHEN date_part('month', reported_date) = date_part('month', current_date) -1 
   AND date_part('year', reported_date) = date_part('year', current_date) then total_orders 
   ELSE 0 END) lastmonthpurchases,
  customer_id,
  mfr_id 
 FROM
  table1
 GROUP BY
  customer_id,
  mfr_id
  IF(lastmonthpurchases * 1.05 < thismonthpurchases OR thismonthpurchases + 5 = thismonthpurchases)
   IF(lastmonthpurchases * 1.05 > thismonthpurchases + 5)
    HAVING
     lastmonthpurchases * 1.05 < thismonthpurchases
   ELSE
    HAVING
     thismonthpurchases + 5 = thismonthpurchases
```

But this does not seem to be working at all, and I can't seem to figure out how to use an aggregate as a conditional in an if statement.

Comment: try using a `having case when ... end`  construct MySQL accepts it maybe postgresql does to.

Comment: also, SQL is not a programming language, so you can't use the constructs like that.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: I suggest you get a good text book or a tutorial on SQL.

Comment: `IF` is not part of SQL and cannot be used. Use CASE, if you have to. And you can't have multiple having's either. Do you some sample data and expected outcome?